# Use of views in jam.py framework

Tags: python, view, frameworks

for an academic project, I am currently using the python framework jam.py 5.4.83 to develop a back office for a new company. 
I would like to use views instead of tables for reporting but I don't find how to do it, I can only import data from tables.
So if someone already used this framework, I would be very thankful.

Regards,
Yoan

Answer (score 0):

The upper part of the Item Editor dialog have the Virtual table field.
Virtual table - if this checkbox is checked, no database table will be created. Use this options to create an item with in-memory dataset or to use its modules to write code. This checkbox must be set when creating an item and can not be changed later.
[Virtual table option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDE8m.png)

Answer (score 0):

the use of database views are not supported in Jam.py
However, you can import tables as read only if used for reporting.
Than you can build Reports as you would.
Good luck.